# Backbone - How to create a nested list with subview list items?

Tags: list, backbone.js, nested

I'm a Backbone noob and I've been at a standstill for 2 days now and can't figure out where I'm going wrong.  Could anyone help me out?

My app is retrieving a JSON file with a list of components in it.  Each component has a category it belongs to.  I create a view called "Components" that is a collapsible list.  When a component category is clicked, it should open up to show the components in that category.  Each of these components (list items) a separate view called "Component".

I'm using a lot of append()'s in the parent view and I don't think this is efficient.  I tried to compile a string of html and then append it to the view in one statement but the events of the subviews weren't triggering.

There are probably a few errors going on here.  Even though my sublist items should be wrapped in ul's they aren't being.  If someone can put me on the path to enlightenment I'd be really grateful!

Here's my code

```
/* ----------------- PARENT VIEW ---------------------- */

var ComponentsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'components-view',
    className: 'components-view',
    html: [
        '<div class="panel panel--components">',
        '<h3 class="panel__heading">add an item</h3>',
        '<ul class="component-list"></ul>',
        '</div>'
    ].join(''),

    initialize: function(){
        var types = [];
        var currentTypeSelected = 1;
        this.getTypes = function(){
            return types;
        }
        this.getCurrentTypeSelected = function(){
            return currentTypeSelected;
        }
        this.setCurrentTypeSelected = function(value){
            currentTypeSelected = value;
        }
        if(this.collection.length){
            this.collection.each(function(model){
                var thisItemType = model.attributes.type;
                if(types.indexOf(thisItemType)==-1){
                    types.push(thisItemType);
                }
            });
        }
        this.$el.html(this.html);
        this.$componentList = this.$('.component-list');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        this.getTypes().forEach(function(type){
            that.$('.component-list').append('<li class="component-type"><a href="#">' + type  + '</a>');
            // now cycle through all the componenets of this type
            that.$('.component-list').append('<ul>');

            that.collection.byType(type).each(function(model){
                that.$('.component-list').append('<li class="component">');
                that.$('.component-list').append(that.renderIndividualComponent(model));
                that.$('.component-list').append('</li>');
            });
            that.$('.component-list').append('</ul>');
        });

    },

     renderIndividualComponent: function(model){
        var componentView = new ComponentView({model: model});
        return componentView.$el;
    },

    events: {
      'click .component-type': 'onOpenSubList'
    },

    onOpenSubList: function (e) {
        alert('open sub list');
    }

});

/* ----------------- SUB (list item) VIEW ---------------------- */

var ComponentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    className: "component", 

    initialize: function(model){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var html = '<a href="#">' + this.model.attributes.description + '</a>'//template(this.model.attributes);
        $(this.el).append(html);
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click a': 'onAddComponent'
    },

    onAddComponent: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('add component');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can suggest you to use templates, underscore has a full functional template engine in it. It all comes with backbone.

Comment: Also create a fiddle if you can and try to separe the problems so it is easier to fix.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying to this.  I have made some progress by using templates for the child list items as you suggested. I am still having issues with the parent <li>'s stopping the events triggering on the child list.  I have tried to set up a fiddle but it is quite hard to abstract the view from its other dependancies.  I will persevere and try and work it out. Thanks again